# Get entire record with max field for each group

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate

There are a lot of answers about this problem, but none of them retrieves the entire record, but only the ID... and I need the whole record.

So, I have a table `status_changes` that is composed of 4 columns:

1. `issue_id` : the issue the change refers to
2. `id`: the id of the change, just a `SERIAL`
3. `status_from` and `status_to` that are infact the status that the issue had before, and the status that the issue got then
4. `when` that is a timestamp of when this happened

Nothing too crazy, but now, I would like to have the "most recent `status_change`" for each issue.

I tried something like:

```
select id
from change 
group by issue_id
having when = max(when)
```

But this has obviously 2 big problems:

1. select contains fields that are not in the group by
   2 having can't contains aggregate function in this way

I thought of "ordering every group by `when` and using something like `top(1)`, but I can't figure out how to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (issue_id)
       id, issue_id, status_from, statue_to, when
FROM change
ORDER BY issue_id, when DESC;
```

This will return the first result (the one with the greatest `when`) for each issue.

Comment: I was just reading about this here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-select.html , thank you so much